# How to reset the current point in cairo?

Tags: cairo, pycairo

From cairo documentation, I can see that some functions, for instance the Text toy-API `cairo_show_text()` needs a current point to be set.
We can set the current point with `cairo_move_to()`, and then calling `cairo_show_text()` it will rasterize the text in the desired location.

Btw, this caused a bug, because after rasterizing text, I was stroking a path, which (with that initial call to `cairo_move_to()` to set the current point for the text) had wrong points.

I solved this bug by calling `cairo_stroke()` immediately after calling `cairo_show_text()`, and it seems to work, since it resets the current point.

It seems that calling `cairo_close_path()` instead of `cairo_stroke()` hasn't been helpful. It didn't reset the current point. And I think this is quite strange. Why?

My final question is: is there a proper way to reset the current point? I think there should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Paths.html#cairo-new-path

> cairo_new_path ()
>
> Clears the current path. After this call there will be no path and no current point.

For completeness: There is also this function which does not clear the current path:

From https://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Paths.html#cairo-new-sub-path

> cairo_new_sub_path ()
>
> Begin a new sub-path. Note that the existing path is not affected. After this call there will be no current point.
>
> In many cases, this call is not needed since new sub-paths are frequently started with cairo_move_to().
>
> A call to `cairo_new_sub_path()` is particularly useful when beginning a new sub-path with one of the `cairo_arc()` calls. This makes things easier as it is no longer necessary to manually compute the arc's initial coordinates for a call to `cairo_move_to()`.